# My Brother B&W Laser Printer - HL 2170W - prints dirty

Tags: hardware-failure, laser-printer

Over time my Brother printer has started printing horizontal gray/black lines on all the print-outs.

More recently, it has started cutting off parts of the words on the left column on the page.

Everything else prints out fine.

I just can't use it for official documents (say Tax returns and such) because the page looks a bit 'dirty'.

It's almost as if I had changed the background color of the pages to light grey....that's how bad it is.

Thoughts?

P.S. I have seen this ever since the end of the last ink cartridge, and it has carried on into the new one.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a 2070 - my manual has instructions for cleaning inside the printer and for cleaning the corona wire - I'd try that first. After that it's probably a replacement drum.

Comment: tried that...but they don't work. The drum was recently replaced. The light on the printer isn't even blinking :(